# Session tracking in jsp to access all properties of Entity class?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I want to use the UserDetailsEntity (Entity class) object in my jsp so when I'm redirecting a user from UserDetailsController.java (Servlet) to home.jsp page, after authentication I want to show his/her username, id, and other properties in his home page with session tracking.

Notice I am using datastore instead of database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session attributes,

Save after authentication User object

```
UserDetailsEntity user ...
request.setAttribute('currentUser', user);
```

and get it in home.jsp

```
request.getAttribute('currentUser');
```

Comment: But after accessing user properties in body of HTML in jsp page under expression tag like <%=  user.name %> it is showing null or "user " cannot resolve to a type..?

Comment: Add to atrribute your UserDetailsEntity object

Comment: here is my jsp code:-<html>
<%
 if ((String) session.getAttribute("uId") != null)

 {
  System.out.print("session succesfully created");
  UserDetailsEntity user = OfyService.ofy().load().type(UserDetailsEntity.class)
    .id((String) session.getAttribute("uId")).now();

 } else {
  response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
 }
%>